# AWS Eventbridge rule trigger once all in-flight sqs messages are processed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-event-bridge

I want to fire off a Lambda when all in-flight messages on my SQS queue are processed.  I can't find much on Terraform's documentation.  Thoughts?  I have most of the terraform complete.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "start_after_in_flight_rule" {
  name        = "start-after-in-flight"
  *Insert rule here**************
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "start_process_target_in_flight" {
  arn  = aws_lambda_function.some_lambda_I_want_to_run.arn
  rule = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.start_after_in_flight_rule.id

  input = <<JSON
{
  "param1": "1",
  "param2": "2"
}
JSON
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "event-invoke-start-process" {
    statement_id = "AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch"
    action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    function_name = aws_lambda_function.some_lambda_I_want_to_run.function_name
    principal = "events.amazonaws.com"
    source_arn    = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.start_after_in_flight_rule.arn
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I can't find much on Terraform's documentation.

You can't find any information about that, because there is no such functionality in TF nor even in AWS. You need a **custom solution** for that. This may include setting an alarm on [SQS metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html) to monitor the number of messages, and triggering the alarm when its empty. Or having some lambda function periodically checking the SQS queue for number of messages, and then triggering some other action.

Comment: Is it possible to make a step function between the parallel lambda functions that take the messages off the queue and the Lambda I want to kick off?  What would that Terraform look like?  Can I just add some type of state machine for  the two Lambdas?

Comment: @Roka There are many ways you can do this. All of them require custom developed solution.